# Firestore collection group queries - how to order parent documents the subcollections are part of?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following data structure:

```
collection/
    parent_document_1/
        timestamp: 0
        subcollection/
            document/
                belongsTo: parent_document_1
                data: data
    
    parent_document_2/
        timestamp: 0
        subcollection/
            document/
                belongsTo: parent_document_1
                data: data

    parent_document_3/
        timestamp: 0
        subcollection/
            document/
                belongsTo: parent_document_1
                data: data
```

I want to sort `parent_documents` by their `timestamp` property, then make a `collectionGroup` query on the `subcollection` collection. I do not want to add an additional property to `documents` because the `timestamp` value under `parent_documents` is the ONLY value I want to sort on. The reason for this is that `documents` can be duplicates of one another, and `timestamp` needs to be updated for each `parent_document` individually.

The bigger picture is that I want to be able to query say, only the 3-5 most recently updated `subcollections`.

Is this possible to do with Firestore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have an alternative to copying the timestamp into the documents in the subcollection that you want to query.

With Firestore, when you query a collection or collection group, you can only use fields immediately within the documents of those collections.  You can **not** reach out and use fields in documents in other collections - this includes both "parent" and "child" documents.  There are no SQL-like "joins" between documents in different collections.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Guess i'll just have to keep my documents (which are supposed to just be simple strings) in an array under the documents nodes.

Comment: Just keep in mind you won't be able to add strings to that array forever since Firestore documents have a maximum size. Doug's solution is preferred/scalable since there's no limit to the number of documents you can have in the subcollection.

Comment: Thanks @Dan I ultimately decided on using "buckets" that store a maximum number of strings that is guaranteed not to interfere with the max document size.